How can I get MPS running in Pytorch on my Apple M2?
I've got the following function to check whether MPS is enabled in Pytorch on my MacBook Pro Apple M2 Max. I get the response:
MPS is not available
MPS is not built

Then I get an error because MPS can't check the version of MacOS if mps doesn't exist.
def check_mps():
    if torch.backends.mps.is_available():
        print("MPS is available")
    else:
        print("MPS is not available")

    if torch.backends.mps.is_built():
        print("MPS is built")
    else:
        print("MPS is not built")

    if torch.backends.mps.is_macos_or_newer(13, 0):
        print("MPS is macOS 13 or newer")
    else:
        print("MPS is not macOS 13 or newer")

I've already verified my OS is up-to-date, and I'm not seeing many other steps to get Pytorch running on Metal. What am I missing?
I tried updating my OS, which is the only recommendation I've found so far. It didn't change anything.

The answer to your question is right in the output you are printing  -- "MPS is not built" -- the version of Pytorch you have has been compiled without MPS support. It cannot use MPS and you cannot change that. To the best of my (limited) knowledge, there are no MPS enabled official Pytorch builds for MacOS

After some more research, I found that mps is only built in the pytorch nightly release, which is installable via:
conda install pytorch-nightly::pytorch -c pytorch-nightly
https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/
